# How symbols are resolved in ruby

Tags: ruby, symbols

A book says that all identifiers and variables we declare/initialize/define in ruby will be included in the internal symbol table as a symbol; then Ruby looks it up whenever the included symbol is used anywhere in the program. For example, in the procedure:

- `a = "1"`
- Ruby includes variable `a` as `:a` inside its table.
- `a` is used in the program:

  ```
  def a
    puts "stack_overflow"
  end
  ```

variable `a` and identifier `def a` have the single symbol `:a` stored in them. I checked the symbol count using `Symbol.all_symbols.count`. The count was the same; i.e., adding `def a` did not increase the symbol table count.

How does ruby discriminate between variable `a` and an identifier `def a` when it sees `a` anywhere in the code?

In `s = :x`, is the symbol variable `s` stored in the symbol table, or just the `:x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The count was the same; i.e., adding `def a` did not increase the symbol table count.

This is because symbol `:a` already exists:

```
$ ruby -e "puts Symbol.all_symbols.count"
2504

$ ruby -e "puts Symbol.all_symbols" | grep ^a | sort | head -n 5
a
abort
abort_on_exception
abort_on_exception=
abs
```

You can start Ruby with the `--disable-gems` options to get rid of it (and many other symbols):

```
$ ruby --disable-gems -e "puts Symbol.all_symbols.count"
1689

$ ruby --disable-gems -e "puts Symbol.all_symbols" | grep ^a | sort | head -n 5
abort
abort_on_exception
abort_on_exception=
abs
abs2
```

Now, defining or referencing `a` actually increases the symbol count:

```
$ ruby --disable-gems -e "puts Symbol.all_symbols.count"
1689

$ ruby --disable-gems -e "def a; end; puts Symbol.all_symbols.count"
1690

$ ruby --disable-gems -e "a = 1; puts Symbol.all_symbols.count"
1690
```

Comment: Stefan thanks!,but  its not about the count i am curious, we know because of the uniqueness properties of symbol the count obviously will not increase, it is totally about the discrimination the ruby makes and how it makes between "a" and the def "a" though both turned into single symbol ":a"

Comment: @RichardGeorge the symbol table is used to keep track of the defined symbols, i.e. it's basically an array of all symbols. It does not store any references to variables or methods.

Comment: FWIW, from The Well Grounded Rubyist, "The symbol table is basically an integer-based hash."

Answer (score 1):

Symbols deep inside are actually a mapping of a constant string to a integer, and after lookup they behave this way, for example - indexing on a symbol is faster than on a string (if hash has symbol keys), also symbol variables consume as much memory as Fixnums

About lookup - ruby has 'environment' for every execution context, which has local variables table, they are nested thus names can be overloaded.
Global scope has context too.

So upon seeing a name (at this time name is already a symbol) - ruby looks for variable with this name in current context, then for methods, then again in parent context etc. (simplified, there are several other things checked)

Comment: :Vas, is there any clear hierarchies there for symbol lookup like what ruby does when looking up methods from object to class to module to 'Class' until Object

Comment: Yes, method is searched in self.class.ancestors, first for exact match, then calling `method_missing`-resolvers

Comment: Btw, `Object` is not on top of hierarchy, `BasicObject` is

Comment: Thanks i missed the basic object :) but single symbol :a  points to "a"  and def "a" how discrimination made  any algorithm if anywhere around i call someobject.a it calls  instance variable or methods?

Comment: instance variables are only accessed in object context via `@variable`, everything else is methods (`attr_accessor` is just a syntax sugar for defining accessor-methods), and they do not need resolution, it's just a ivar-table lookup by symbol

Comment: symbol do not point to anything, they are just names, you can think of them as of array indexes for example - if you have two arrays - `a = ['string']` and `b = [lambda{ puts 'this is lambda'}]`, then "symbol" `0` will have some similarity - by itself it is just a value, by which you can fetch something in other place